# How do you split a list of stings into an unevenly list with sized chunks?

Tags: python, list, chunks

Is there a way to split in chunks a string inside a list by defining the length in another list?

So, I've implemented a program using the nltk library to stem my information.

I´ve segmented it using the word_tokenize function and then used nltk.stem.snowball.SnowballStemmer to cut parts of the word.

I want to group up the info back to the same length since the SnowballStemmer makes me put it to a single list unchunk.

I´ve tried to use the function I found in similar questions

```
def agrup(oglista,separlist): #-oglist= base list -separlist=size

    for i in range (0,len(oglista),separlist):
        yield oglista[i:i + separlist]


# Main program
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
lista = ["Muy interesante y entretenido", "Mas didáctica", "Mas dinámico", "Importante", "Paseo de estudio", 
         "Es bastante útil.", "Desearía tener una asesoría completa y correcta", "denso", "Buen curso", "Muy exigente"]  #original list

stemmers1 =[]

Snowball_stemmer = SnowballStemmer('spanish')

for i in range(len(lista1)):

    stemmers = [Snowball_stemmer.stem(word) for word in lista1[i]] 

    for i in range (len(stemmers)):

        stemmers1.append(stemmers[i])

lista1 = [['Muy', 'interesante', 'y', 'entretenido'], ['Mas', 'didáctica'], ['Mas', 'dinámico'], ['Importante'], ['Paseo', 'de', 'estudio'], ['Es', 'bastante', 'útil', '.'], ['Desearía', 'tener', 'una', 'asesoría', 'completa', 'y', 'correcta'], ['denso'], ['Buen', 'curso'], ['Muy', 'exigente']]  #tokenized list

stemmers1 = ['muy', 'interes', 'y', 'entreten', 'mas', 'didact', 'mas', 'dinam', 'import', 'pase', 'de', 'estudi', 'es', 'bastant', 'util', '.', 'des', 'ten', 'una', 'asesor', 'complet', 'y', 'correct', 'dens', 'buen', 'curs', 'muy', 'exigent']  #stemmed list

#This is the code I used for forming the group

for s in range (len(lista1[s])):

        stemmers2=agrup(stemmers1, s)

print(stemmers2)
```

Error:

```
builtins.NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

Expected Output:

```
stemmers2=[['muy', 'interes', 'y', 'entreten'], ['mas', 'didact'], ['mas', 'dinam'], ['import'], ['pase', 'de', 'estudi'], ['es', 'bastant', 'util', '.'], ['des', 'ten', 'una', 'asesor', 'complet', 'y', 'correct'], ['dens'], ['buen', 'curs'], ['muy', 'exigent']]
```

Am I writing wrong the called function? Or does it not work for this kind of use? Is there a better way to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please include the expected output.  Describe the problem in terms of the posted code, not vague references to items that aren't included.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your iteration range:

```
for s in range (len(lista1[s])):
                           ^   here, "s" is not defined.
```

Python has no idea what element of `lista1` you want.

Comment: I planned to use the index of the list as a definer since that "for" is inside another "for" making it go around all the list. Am I being clear? I'm sorry I am not a natural english speaker so I can't express myself well.

Comment: No, it isn't inside another `for`.  You have only *one* `for` here.  If you expect some sort of nesting, you will have to write it.  The `s` on the left takes on a sequence of values, based indirectly on the `s` on the right.  Until that right-side `s` has a value, that expression is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to get set/unique list? 
If so, please try this

```
stemmers1 = ['muy', 'interes', 'y', 'entreten', 'mas', 'didact', 'mas', 'dinam', 'import', 'pase', 'de', 'estudi', 'es', 'bastant', 'util', '.', 'des', 'ten', 'una', 'asesor', 'complet', 'y', 'correct', 'dens', 'buen', 'curs', 'muy', 'exigent']

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in stemmers1:
    d[''.join(sorted(i))].append(i)
out = [tuple(i) for i in d.values() if len(i) > 1]
print(out)
```

```
[('muy', 'muy'), ('y', 'y'), ('mas', 'mas')]
```

Comment: I've uploaded extra part of my code, it is supposed for the code to make a loop for the length in every item in lista. Like in lista[0]= 4, lista[1]=2, etc. being that the definer for the length for the chunk.

Answer (score 0):

's' should be defined if your using within range.

try the below code:

```
for s in range (0, len(lista1)+1):

        stemmers2=agrup(stemmers1, s)
```

If you are still looking for answer, then can you please illustrate with an example.